# jQuery or JavaScript method of finding an elements off set to the window when the element is in a relative position element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, position, positioning

I have a couple elements that are stuck in containers that are set to relative positioned parents. To which these elements need to have a custom tool tip added to them, the tooltip is a fixed position element that is outside of the relative elements. So setting offsets based on the parent elements of the elements in question when the fixed element is trying to work with the window as its offset is making it difficult to ge the fixed element to line up under the elements we want them to.

I would attempt to show the mess that is the code I have tried but its just that garbage at this point cause ive gone so many directions outside of the apparent right one that I am missing that it needs to be rewritten. So before I do that I need to figure out how to get the position of the elements I need to line the fixed element up with.

I hope that makes sense. In short I need the position based on the window, not the parent ideas?

Quick example of Code not exactly the code but showing it for sake of example

```
<body>
   <div style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;">
       Some text more text <span class="something">Trigger text</span>
    </div>
    <div style="position:fixed"></div>
</body>
```

The above is a very simple example of the code we are talking about. My problem is, the div with relative is a colorbox lightbox plugin, and also one of the templates containing elements outside of that is also an element with relative positioning and `overflow` set to hidden. Problem with using absolute and surprisingly (fixed as well) position in the same element that is the element with relative is the is that if the element I want displayed only at certain times is larger than the containing element its set in, the overflow eats it and it falls into the void so to speak. The only workaround I have been able to make work was putting a fixed position element down at the bottom of the document that I can then tell to show when and where needed. Problem with that is its using the overall window's left and top to position from rather cause the element in the relative container says its offset is 100 top and 50 left which is expected overall considering the elements at play. So the hope is to find a way to find the elements top left relative to the document itself rather then the parent element

Comment: Did you use jQuery's [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)? Did it not work?

Comment: Yes, it seems to only capture the offset from the parent that set to relative, cause the fixed element positions itself according the right amount of pixels from the top/left of the window itself that it would in the element of the element I am trying to line up with

Comment: So than add it to the postion of the parent.

Comment: Although you did describe your problem, it is greatly appreciated to be able to see some code. Consider adding some code so that your question will have a much higher value

Comment: very loose example and further details added

Answer (score 0):

A bit of code or a diagram showing what you are trying to achieve would help a lot. 
jQuery provides a couple of methods you can use to find the position of elements. You may need to set your tooltips and any child elements of the containers to `position:absolute` in your css for it to work correctly.

`offset()` returns an object containing the left and top positions of an element from the top-left corner of the document.

`position()` returns an object containing the left and top position of an element from the top-left corner of its nearest positioned ancestor.

`scrollTop()` and `scrollLeft()` return how many pixels of document exists above and to the left of the browser window.

Hope this is of some help to you.

This info taken from '[Javascript & jQuery - the missing manual](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920015048.do)'